# Parameter dataFormatType is a mandatory field and cannot be empty. Please check the properties view for more details

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

how to solve this problem.i am beginner " jboss middleware"
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4STG.png

Parameter dataFormatType is a mandatory field and cannot be empty. Please check the properties view for more details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
<!-- this is the JDBC data source Config for postgresql database -->
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
<!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent" id="sql">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<camelContext id="CustInfoContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:sql.properties"/>
    <route customId="true" id="custinfoRoute">
        <from id="_from1" uri="activemq:queue:customer"/>
        <unmarshal id="_unmarshal1">
            <jaxb contextPath="org.blogdemo.homeloan.model"
                partClass="org.blogdemo.homeloan.model.CustInfo" prettyPrint="true"/>
        </unmarshal>
        <setHeader headerName="custNationalID" id="_setHeader1">
            <simple>${body.nationalID}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="firstName" id="_setHeader2">
            <simple>${body.firstName}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="lastName" id="_setHeader3">
            <simple>${body.lastName}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="age" id="_setHeader4">
            <simple>${body.age}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="occupation" id="_setHeader5">
            <simple>${body.occupation}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to id="_to1" uri="sql:{{sql.insertCustInfo}}"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please post the relevant code into the question, links to screen shots don't allow users to copy and paste your code easily..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that is a problem in the Beta1 version of the tooling. In the latest sources I can't reproduce this issue. See attached screenshots. I'd suggest to upgrade to the latest version as soon as it is released.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio 9.1.0.Beta2 and jboss fuse tooling version 8.0

Comment: 8.0 is not the exact version. Could you be more specific?

Comment: jboss fuse tooling version 8.0.0.Beta1-v20160222-1935-B731

Comment: We can't reproduce the exact same error but found a bug with the prettyPrint attribute. Tracked here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-1788